# Dynamic vector or fixed array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, routes, heuristics

I am fairly new to C++ and I am doubting between two options. I am designing a metaheuristic for a specific type of routing problem, and I need to perform many changes.

A route is currently represented by a vector of integers, each integer representing a customer index. The solution contains multiple route vectors. Since at runtime both the lengt of each of these route vectors and the number of routes needed is decided, I opted to choose for vectors rather than arrays since it allows for easy dynamic allocation.

However, I know the maximum possible length of the routes and the number of routes. I could alternatively create a large solution of fixed size (in an array?) with many zeros, and perform all operations manually when reassigning customers within or between routes.

Since I perform many operations I am wondering which of these two options is the faster one in terms of computations speed. Of course my heuristic needs to be as efficient as possible!

Comment: you can use `std::vector::reserve()` to pre-allocate the vector of desired size, so no need for zeroes. Other than that, there should be no reason for any notable difference in speed

Comment: however some functions of std::array have constexpr specifier, which means there are computed at compile time, so there might be a slight difference

Comment: @MarekChocholáček the problem is most of those functions are related to array size, and in this case actual size will not be determined until runtime. Yes, the "reserved" size will be constexpr-available, but what for?

Comment: @Ap31 you are absolutely right

Comment: @Ap31 thank you, I wasn't aware of `std::vector::reserve()`. This seems very useful.